# C++/CX restrictions

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I want to write a library using C++/CX syntax and use it in other projects.

As you know, plain old data structures cannot have any methods or operators, so we had to do things like writing static methods in another class to provide behavior.

Also we can't write code like this :

```
private:
    int _D;
public:
    property int& D { int& get() {return _D;}}
```

or pass this property to methods like this:

```
void SampleMethod(int& d);
```

I don't know why the Windows Runtime Library has these restrictions.

How can I compile C++/CX and Windows Runtime extensions in a .lib file? Or how do I precompile the whole WRL project's code files in another project?

Comment: What's "WRL" and "public value struct"? What are you trying to do, really?

Comment: A `struct` in C++ is just a way to make a class that have public members by default, while a `class` have private members by default. That is the only difference between a class and a struct.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "C++11" and not "C#"?

Comment: WRL is most likely Windows Runtime Library, a native API for targeting WinRT (sandboxed Metro-style UI) in the yet to be released Windows 8.

Comment: Yes i mean c++11. i want to write a .lib file in c++11 and use it in another project like a DirectX Application in windows 8. but compiler error is LNK1326: archiving OBJ compiled with /ZW into static lib is not supported

Comment: The next MS compiler is VC++11, just to confuse us about the new language standard C++11.

Comment: The proper name for the language with extensions is C++/CX - I've updated it accordingly. Also, WRL is the template library that ships with VC++ to enable "low-level" (with no language extensions) access to WinRT - this code does not use it in any way. The ABI/runtime itself - what you target when you compile with /ZW - is called WinRT.

Comment: After Pavel's comment, I changed the title from "WRL restrictions" to "C++/CX restrictions" since I believe it more accurately reflects the intent of the author.

Comment: POD types in C++11 actually can have operators and member functions. I think the relaxed requirements are just that they have to have standard layout and trival ctor,dtor, and assignment op.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinRT is an ABI that is intended for cross-language use - at least C++, C#, VB and JS. For this reason, the constructs it provides are limited to what can be represented in those languages in a straightforward way - for example, if you return by reference, how would C# code use that?

If you want to write a static library in C++ for consumption only from C++, my advice would be to avoid language extensions inasmuch as possible, and only keep them for those places where you have to pass WinRT objects around. There's no benefit you will derive in that scenario from going full C++/CX.

Comment: how about futures like reference counting. i just care about win 8.

Comment: You can have reference counting with standard C++ classes using `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: reference counting is the boost::instrusive_ptr, the shared_ptr is not the same at all and pretty much all users need to know about it. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Comment: @AlexisWilke shared_ptr is also reference counting, it just keeps the reference separate from the object - though even that is no longer true with `std::make_shared` in C++11. For all practical purposes, `shared_ptr` + `make_shared` are all that you need for refcounted objects in C++, unless you're doing micro-optimizations. `intrusive_ptr` is there for the latter, or when you have an existing refcounting system that lacks a smart pointer (like COM).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike C++, where a "struct" is basically "a class where all the members are public", in the windows runtime, a "struct" is a value type.  As such, it cannot have any methods, including property accessors (value types can't have methods).

In addition, because structs are value types, they are always passed by value. This means that passing a struct into a method requires copying the contents of the struct (a value type implies that every consumer operates on their own copy of the data type).  As a consequence of this, structs should be fairly small in size (think "under 16 bytes").

If you need to pass around larger objects, use a class instead - classes are passed by reference and thus can hold any amount of data.

Comment: The rationale sounds weak - I mean, there's no generic definition of "value type" which precludes them from having methods, and they do have them in e.g. .NET. I'm pretty sure there is a rationale for that design in WinRT, but it would be interesting to know. Is it some versioning problem?

Comment: Pavel: While it's true that JS and C# don't have a "value type" construct, C++ *does* have a value type - it's called "POD".  Windows Runtime structs are simply C++ POD (with the weird restriction that strings are logically POD but in fact aren't (this is because windows runtime strings are value types even though they're internally implemented as pointers)).

Comment: C# empathically _does_ have a value type construct. It's called "value type", and is any type derived from `System.ValueType` :) As for C++ PODs, I'm not sure what makes them "value type" compared to any other C++ class, as they are all passed by value; but, regardless, there was never any prohibition on PODs having member functions in C++, either. Anyway, saying "structs can't have methods in WinRT because they are value types" doesn't really explain much - the next obvious question would then be, "why value types can't have methods in WinRT?".

Comment: Pavel: Value types can't have methods because they don't have a vtable - they're POD.  Remember that all types with methods in the windows runtime have a vtable to hold the methods (reference types are IUnknown based).  value types don't have vtables so they can't have methods.

Comment: You don't need a vtable on the object itself to provide methods, however. On ABI level, it could be done in the same exact way static methods are done, via an associated special-purpose interface - but exposed as instance members in language projections.

Comment: @Pavel: The bottom line is that Windows Runtime value types don't have methods.  Windows Runtime value types are essentially C++ POD and just like C++ POD doesn't have methods, Windows Runtime value types don't have methods.  There are some fairly deep technical reasons for this and I'd be more than happy to discuss them with you over email, but this isn't the forum for those discussions.